# ngb-tabset & dynamically created tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 5.2.10 (also tested in 5.0.2) + Bootstrap 4.1.1 (also tested in 4.0.0) + ng-bootstrap 1.1.2 and trying to make `tab-set` working with dynamically created tabs.

I'm binding `ngb-tab`s to an array via `*ngFor`:

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab
      id="tab.id"
      *ngFor="let tab of tabs">

        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
            <span>{{ tab.title }}</span>

            <span
                class="close"
                (click)="onClosiClick(tab)">
                &times;
            </span>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbTabContent>Content of {{ tab.title }}</ng-template>

    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

But this pretty simple template has 3 issues:

1. When adding multiple tabs, their content is displayed one below
   the other.
2. Can't switch between tabs.
3. When clicking on Close (x) button in the example, the app gets reloaded.

Here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-tab-set-issues). Also, I've crated an [issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2355) on Github.

Am I doing something wrong or this is a missing functionality in `ng-bootstrap` yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id is being set to the string of `"tab.id"`. Instead I think it should be `[attr.id]="tab.id"` which will set the id attribute to the value held in `tab.id`

It looks like there is an open issue on the ng-bootstrap repo that has a temporary solution for the app reloading.
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1909

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-tab-set-issues-fj8koq?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You're right, thank you! This fixes issues #1 and #2. However, when clicking on Close (x) button, the app reloads. Do you know why it is so?

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that. I updated the answer with info on how to prevent the reloads

Comment: Great, thank you for the fixes and for pointing to the existing issue on this!